# Laravel 5.5 - get data from model where realated model has no data in specific month

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get some data from a specific model, where the related model has no data in the current month.

Something like

```
Select * FROM houses 
JOIN customers
WHERE "there is no customer for the current month;
```

But in Laravel.

I tried multiple things out but couldn't do the trick.

I have a `house` table. 
The house table has many `customers`.

Now I want to get all `houses` where there is no `customer` for the current Month.

I tried something like:

```
House::whereMonth('House.customers.created_at', Carbon::now()->format('m'))->get();
```

One solution that worked for me is:

```
$houses= House::all();
$customers = Customer::whereNotExists(function($query) use ($houses){
    $query->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('m'));
})->get();
```

Does somebody have a more cleaner way?

SQL Table structure:

customer:

```
'id', 'house_id', 'name', 'created_at','updated_at'
```

houses:

```
'id', 'name', 'created_at','updated_at'
```

Now I want to get all houses that has no customers for the current month

Comment: This is quite good solution

Comment: Well, right know I see that I get only customers data back with realated house data. I would like to have it the other way around. I should say I only want the house data. I only need the customer data for checking.

Comment: could you please add sql tables structure?

Comment: I did :) ......

Comment: I think you could use `hasMany()` for this matter mixed with the `whereMonth()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `whereHas` like that

```
House::whereHas('consumers' , function($query){
 $query->whereMonth('created_at' , '<>' , Carbon::now()->format('m'));
})->get();
```